# MVC 4 view (cshtml) error is not logging to Splunk via log4net

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net, splunk

I have implemented error handling code to log exceptions to Splunk (using log4net) wherever they occur in my MVC 4 application. The problem is that when an exception arises within a view file (cshtml), there is no matching Splunk log for the exception.

I debugged through the code and found that all the right methods are being called. When I check the value that's being passed into the ILog.Error(string message) method, the value is:

```
System.Exception: Test view exception
   at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\dev\MyMVCApp\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 5
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

All other log attempts are successful except for messages logged from view exceptions. My log4net config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />

        <!-- snip -->
    </configSections>

    <!-- snip -->

    <log4net>
        <appender name="SplunkAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender">
            <remoteAddress value="splunk.myawesomeserver.com" />
            <remotePort value="2221" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <ConversionPattern value="[%-5p] (%c) %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="SplunkAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Do I have this configured wrong? Is there a way to find out what's going wrong once I hand the message off to ILog.Error()?

Comment: Just wanted to leave a link to a SplunkTCP adapter (I have not tried it) https://code.google.com/p/splunk-log4net/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSplunk.Log4net

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be several things :

1) Have you enabled UDP port 2221 on splunk.myawesomeserver.com and confirmed that the port is open and listening ?

2) are there any firewalls potentially blocking the UDP traffic

3) what search command are you using in Splunk that is leading you to determine that the events did not get indexed by Splunk ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, splunk messages are showing up. It's the ones I'm NOT getting that I'm worried about. There are many instances where some show up in splunk, but not all of the log messages. I think it might be an issue with the way I'm formatting the log messages. Splunk might not be able to interpret them. I haven't had time yet, but I'm going to try to implement a custom "PatternLayout" that conforms with http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/UnderstandandusetheCommonInformationModel

Comment: It appears to be a log message size issue. It works with all small log messages, but when I log a few paragraphs, it doesn't show up in splunk. However, Wireshark says it's being sent from the server logging the message. Not sure how to fix it to allow messages of any size...

Comment: A few things to consider : 1) UDP is not a reliable transport mechanism , 2) if you can I would recommend formatting your log messages in a best practice semantic format, http://dev.splunk.com/view/logging-best-practices/SP-CAAADP6 , 3) look at the spec for the UDP stanza in inputs.conf,  http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/inputsconf , you can tweak the receive buffer size